# Broken text in Unity canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

For no particular reason text in our grid gets completely broken sometimes. The underlying string is correct - it's the UI that's messed up.

Looks like this

[image]

Comment: "The object in question is not even the one being updated when it breakes" If you can make a duplicate of this project, delete everything in it except for the `Text` and the code you use to change it then share the project, that would be good.I will take a look at it. I think it is hard to tell what's going on from here. This sounds more like a bug so it would make sense to mention the Unity version in your question.

Comment: Was this screen taken from the Game view or from the Scene view ? It often happens that on a scene with a lot of Text components, the fonts get kind of "corrupted" and display weirdly as it did here (then you simply have to edit one of them to fix it). Otherwise I don't really know what could cause this.

Comment: Its the game view

Comment: Its Unity 5.4.2f2

Comment: Changing the font without triggering a mesh recalculation might cause this.

Comment: Have not run into this bug for a long time now, we are on 5.5.4

Comment: I've also had this issue with fonts rendering incorrectly for many Unity versions using Windows standalone builds. I'm currently on Unity 2017.3.1f1. It happens very rarely though...

Comment: Havent happened for me in ages. Not since 5.5 and after

Answer (score 1):

Try removing that text component and adding a new one. Or if you could, please try Unity 2018 or 2019.

Comment: Havent seen this bug in years. We are on Unity 2019.3 but I think it was fixed somewhere in 5.x

Comment: I mentioned 5.5.4  above

Comment: Alright! The occurrence of such bug is rarely in 5.5.4 above